# Get other ID's value in form using .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to display the value of a text field onclick of the Search button.

On the search button, I'm using

```
onclick="document.getElementByid('output').innerHTML = this.value"
```

This gets the value of the Search button, which is just 'Search' and displays it in a 'output' div below.

Is there a way to use this to get the value of a separate text field once it is filled in by the user?

I've tried changing **this.value** to **field1.value** where field1 is the id/name of the text field, but this does not work.

Any help?

Comment: `document.getElementById('field1').value`

Comment: This fetch the value of text field with id

Comment: Ahaa, yes. Perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
document.getElementByid('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('field1').value
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the value in the output div there, even after refreshing the page?

Comment: Use local storage or session storage. I would recommend session storage for this. But why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**example**):

```
var btn = document.getElementById('search');
var input = document.getElementById('field1');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  output.innerHTML = input.value;

});
```